# What Exactly Is a Redis Instance?

Tags: parallel-processing, redis

I'm new to Redis and hope to be able to perform reads from the database as fast as possible.

I figure that if I can implement parallelism it should improve the performance and I read that having multiple Redis instances might be the way to achieve this.

I'm a bit confused as to what exactly a Redis instance is though. Is it another node within a Redis cluster and if so can an instance be either a slave or a master?

Answer (score 6):

A Redis instance usually refers to the Redis software server process. A single physical/virtual server can run multiple software processes, Redis or others. This makes it possible to have a server with multiple Redis instances on it.

Each Redis instance has a run mode and a role. The possible run modes are either standalone or cluster. The possible roles are either master or slave. In standalone mode you can have no more and no less than one master instance - it is in charge of the entire database (shared/numbered databases are just namespacing inside that database). Optionally, you may add one or more slave instances for high-availability (managed by Sentinel for example) or to offload reads from the master.

In cluster mode the database (note that shared/numbered databases are not supported by the cluster) is partitioned into hash slots. Each of the master instances that belong to the cluster is in charge of one or more slots at any given time. A cluster's master instance can have slave instances, although these are usually for HA purposes only, which is handled internally by the cluster. Scaling the cluster is usually achieved just by throwing in new masters and migrating slots them. In the context of a Redis cluster, a node is just a server that runs one or more instances.

Comment: Mostly, yes. I was debating internally whether to throw that it but felt that more is less in this case.

Comment: Please read the docs - http://redis.io/topics/latency: "Redis is _mostly_ single threaded since actually from Redis 2.4 we use threads in Redis in order to perform some slow I/O operations in the background, mainly related to disk I/O, but this does not change the fact that Redis serves all the requests using a single thread.". Also note that in the upcoming version we'll be getting LAZYDEL and others :)

Comment: Understood, though my comment still stands. Redis is still single threaded as the link clearly says "this does not change the fact that Redis serves all the requests using a single thread". We are splitting hairs. I'm the one that up-voted your answer :)

Comment: I figured as much wrt upvote - thanks :) and wrt to hairsplitting, I have _mostly_ no hair ;P

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry for my lack of knowledge but take this for an example which might help me understand this a bit better. I create a Redis database, I then create an instance of this database. Would this instance then become either a master or a slave depending on how I configure it? Also in regards to Redis being single threaded, would the creation of more Redis instances work around it being single threaded since each instance would use an available core each?

Comment: Master/slave roles are set by the `slaveof` configuration directive and/or the `SLAVEOF` command. Creating more masters, and thus harnessing the power of additional cores, is possible only in the cluster - with the standalone mode you can use only a single core for the entire database.